# Plot DataFrame groupby with multiindex for a specific index

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some data coming from a series of executions. I massaged the data to get a structure which "feels good".

The table is multiindex. There is a `nodes` index, which is the one I want in the plot, and a `size` index, which will be `groupby`-ed. I arrived to this structure by the following:

```
ws_data = df.query("...").pivot_table(index=["nodes", "size"], ...).groupby(level="size")

ws_data.plot(y="time")
```

However, the x axis has the tuple `(nodes, size)`, which I would like to avoid. I only need to paint the nodes, which is the variable that changes in a single plot, and I want to use the `size` for the plot title.

I have been struggling with flags of the [groupby.Plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.plot.html) as well as if [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) can simplify or drop that intermediate index.

Am I doing something very wrong? Or I am overlooking something? It feels like I am near my result, but maybe I am misusing the tools.

---

To simulate the structure and the plot I am having:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"time": np.random.random(6)},
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [[1, 2, 4], [4096, 8192]], 
        names=['nodes', 'size']
    )
)

ws_data = df.groupby(level="size")
ws_data.plot(y="time")
```